# How do you indent > < without leaving visual mode and losing your current selection?

Tags: indentation, visual-mode

I often have to manually indent, but when I enter a visual mode, select my lines to indent, and press `<` or `>`, I leave visual mode whether I want to or not.

I would rather have it so I stay in visual mode, and keep my selection and cursor position intact.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is there any chance a remapping would do the trick ? Something like `:vmap < <a` ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have this in my vimrc:

```
"keep visual mode after indent
vnoremap > >gv
vnoremap < <gv
```

Note that you could also simply use `.` (dot) to repeat the last indent action.

Comment: Almost perfect, save that my cursor does not move with the row.

Comment: @Akiva Maybe you want to add a `^` at the end of that mapping? i.e. `>gv^`?

Comment: The cursor seems to move (or not) depending on its position with respect to the indented text. It's not clear for me where do you want the cursor to stay: at the same column number, or on the same character? Also, you know that you can still move the cursor e.g. with `j`, `k`, `l` etc. while *in* visual mode?

Comment: Honestly, I just put `<Right>` And `<Left>` after the commands, and that worked fine.

Answer (score 10):

I know this isn't an automatic solution, but you can accomplish this by using `gv` after the visual indent.

This will go into visual mode with the previous selection selected, and your cursor at the last line. See `:h gv` for more info.

Answer (score -1):

I tried adding the following mapping to my vimrc :

```
vmap < <a
vmap > >a
```

It seems to have interesting results, maybe that's what you're looking for ?