# Any ergonomic way to shift block of code to left and right in vim and neovim?

Tags: neovim, original-vim

I have some key mappings for the block of code up and down

```
vnoremap J :m '>+1<CR>gv=gv
vnoremap K :m '<-2<CR>gv=gv
```

So I tried to do the same with H and L

```
vnoremap H <V
vnoremap L >V
```

It not actually what I want( Shift the code but still stay in visual mode).

Comment: You should modify your title to be more specific. By shift, you mean move blocks of text up and down, not left and right.

Comment: Frankly I find it easier to push `<` and then `.` as needed. But I don’t use visual mode as often as perhaps you do

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8433/10604

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are about shifting block of text left or right then `:h gv` you are using for the `J` and `K` does what you want: reselects previous visual selection:

```
xnoremap H <gv
xnoremap L >gv
```

Note, `xnoremap` instead of `vnoremap` is preferred unless you also want those mappings in `SELECT` mode too.